# how can get the Google SOAP API key

Tags: php, html

I am doing my work with Search Engine PHP scripts process with Google clone. I want a Google soap API key. What should I do for get that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/08/well-earned-retirement-for-soap-search.html

It's no longer available.

They encourage you to use this: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html